# html email problem with posted php variable

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am working to send email with the html body. Body html is posted by php variable with ajax. but all html will be ignored.

for example in email.php

HTML element

```
<textarea id="html" cols="20" name="TextArea1" rows="2">HTML code is here</textarea>
```

Javascript

```
var html = $("#html").val();
$.post("function.php", {  html: html }, function(data) {

    if(data){
    //do sth

        }
        });
```

and in function php

```
$body = "";
    $body .= $_POST['html'];

  //send email
```

I tried `html_entity_decode` but no luck. the email is sent, comes without html elements. how can i do this ?

Thanks

EDIT: I got the problem, in HTML there is ' character and it disrupts the HTML structure.

But how can i avoid this, i still don't know...

EDIT 2 : stripslashes() made it ! Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I would get firebug and try to walk the process through in the browser & watch what exactly you are passing along to the php page.  You may find that you're not posting anything.  I imagine if PHP got it it should be at least be able to print it out for you as an echo.

Comment: i did it, it is passing HTML code perfectly. but when it sends email, only text appears without HTML elements (tables,cells etc..) in the email...

Answer (score 0):

What does the email sending code look like? To send HTML you need to include additional headers, see example #4 in the php docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: i use phpmailer, and all settings are ok for html email, it should be about variables, dunno :S

Answer (score 0):

If (') be your problem means try

```
 $layout = addslashes($_POST['html']);
```

It will add backslash like (\') to the values.